# Is it safe to update WooCommerce data update?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Hi I just switched woocomerce version from 3.0.9 to 3.1.0. And I received this mesage "WooCommerce data update – We need to update your store database to the latest version"

So can I udpate safely woocommerce data?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting this question I had the same. I don't know why it was down marked but since I had the same question I up marked you.

Answer (score 1):

Login in to your hosting back-end and perform full WordPress database backup, or ask your hosting provider to do so. Then You can safely revert, if something goes wrong.
I have just done it (the update You asked about) on my test site and nothing broke ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you take a backup of your website files and database before running any updates to avoid losing data so you could always revert if you do have issues.

That said, I would say it would be fine to update the database.